# NodeJs : dotenv not working for nested paths

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I have react project with my own custom file structure. 
Here is an image for the project structure.
[image: File structure]

My index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({path:'../.env'});
console.log(process.env)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

.env

```
API_URL = http://54.254.198.83:1441/
```

console output

```
{NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: ""}
```

Why are the .env variables not added to process.env ?

Comment: Hello @vivek-iyver, I have the same issue, did you solve your problem ? 
thank you.

Comment: Hi @Skyd,
You can try the method mentioned in accepted answer.
Alternatively you can try renaming your variables with `REACT_APP_${your_variable}` . (Recommended way that is mentioned in React docs)
In your case for e.g:-
`API_URL` should be `REACT_APP_API_URL`.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my problem after restart the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you get `dotenv` working with nested paths:

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'relative/path/to/your/.env'})
```

Place this at the top of the file you want your .env vars available within.

Comment: i have the same problem, but only when i'm running my tests. The query works fine.